# Error when Try to send newsletter

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to send a newsletter to my clients.

- So I go to **Marketing** --> **Newsletter template** and then **add template do
  queue**.

After this I set:  ***Queue Date Start*** for example "*send messages at 31.01.2018 19:23*" and then click **Save Newsletter**.

After save I get error code:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (31 sty 2018 18:37:37) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character

Exception #0 (Exception): DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (31 sty 2018 18:37:37) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character
#0 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Queue.php(185): DateTime->__construct('31 sty 2018 18:...')
#1 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Controller/Adminhtml/Queue/Save.php(55): Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue->setQueueStartAtByString('31 sty 2018 18:...')
#2 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Adminhtml/Queue/Save/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save->execute()
#3 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#4 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#7 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Newslet...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#8 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Newslet...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#11 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Adminhtml/Queue/Save/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#14 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Queue\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#18 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#21 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#23 /home/b2b/domains/istyled.pl/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#24 {main}
```

Please note: *When I do not set  **Queue Date Start** (only the empty field will remain) and then save I does not get this error but e-mail marketing it is not sent.

- Non-stop newsletter have status "Sending" "processed: 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be because the timestamp you're passing "31 sty 2018 18:37:37" (what does sty mean?) isn't the correct date format for php, it should be

```
2018-01-31 18:37:37
```

I think. It may just be me being ignorant but what does 'sty' denote? 
Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it was your good idea! I have language packet installed for magento back-end. this date has also been translated by what magento gives an error. (this is  mistake of people who were responsible for the translation). So now I have changed language version in back-end to  traditional magento English and now all works ! Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Glad I could help, it'd be dope if you could accept my answer but awesome!